# How to properly PDF forms programmatically made with Adobe LiveCycle Designer

Tags: python, pdf, automation

Traditional Adobe Acrobat forms that are filled using PYPDF2 or pdfrw do not display properly in Acrobat---the text is invisible until you click on it. The same thing happens when you fill these forms out with Preview on a mac.

The solution is to run this function on the form:

```
t = pdfrw.PdfReader('a form.pdf')
t.pages[0]['/Annots'][4].update(pdfrw.PdfDict(V='some text that goes into field 4'))
t.Root.AcroForm.update(pdfrw.PdfDict(NeedAppearances=pdfrw.PdfObject("true")))
pdfrw.PdfWriter().write('foo2.pdf',t)
```

After a lot of experimentation, I've determined that this approach doesn't work with forms created by Adobe LiveCycle Designer. And indeed, when I try to open these forms with Acrobat, I get this lovely error message:

[image]

So my question is --- is there some way to edit these forms properly?

I suspect that the problem may be my specific form doesn't have fonts set up properly, so I would settle for being able to specify the fonts for the fields.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the advice and procure Livecycle Designer.

Or recreate the forms using Acroforms instead of XFA…